# Does WebDriver simulate mouse clicks?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, page-objects

The question came to me from our team, we are using the WebDriver for our browser testing and accessing our pages using the Page Object model.  There is a sporadic problem with a page that begins to load but doesn't fully display due to background processes.  I was asked if the access is using mouse clicks, which is something I don't remember if WebDriver is doing.

I may be misremembering, but I thought that WebDriver somehow went around the use of the mouse but don't know if the underlying functionality of WebDriver is still acting on page buttons and other objects as if it was a mouse click.  Does it still work that way, or is WebDriver using a different methodology to access objects and activate them?

Comment: Page object is just a code design pattern, not a magic wand. It does what you (or your coders) wrote. Use the source, Luke! You have your code and we don't.

Comment: @PeterMasiar Yeah, I kind of forgot that when trying to get this down in trying to figure out what we are doing.  Some of our methods do use click, some don't and I was trying to figure out if the ones that don't are still acting like a mouse or not.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that Selenium simulates actual mouse clicks when you use .Click() on a WebElement. The purpose of Selenium in end to end testing is to simulate the actual experience a user will have and that includes using a mouse to click on the elements in a web page.

Comment: -1, it doesn't simulate "actual mouse clicks" like Coded UI or Sikuli does. You can run Selenium tests on a minimized or headless browser so the actual mouse pointer isn't used. Instead they are fired through the WebDriver protocol, in some cases apps may show different behavior than with real clicks by a user.

Comment: This is actually close to what I was trying to remember, with the headless tests I was sure we skipped past the mouse actions, but when the browser is up I wasn't sure if it did the same when click was not used

Answer (score 0):

As @PeterMasiar points out, Page Objects are a design pattern that can be used with Selenium Webdriver but they are not integral to it.  They can be implemented in a number of different ways and can also be used in other non-webdriver projects.

I consider Page Objects to come in three forms:

### Locators

There are the basic building blocks.  Organizations usually start with these. Some organizations will only create these types of Page Objects.  They identify HTML element(s) within a web page using css and xpath.  Examples:

`div.header span.user form`
`span#top_header input`
`div//span[2]//table`

### Actions

These build on top of Locators and include actions such as find element, mouse click, drag and drop, submit form, etc.  Examples:

```
find(login_submit).submit
find(user_email_opt_out).click
```

### Procedures

This is the highest level of abstraction and comprises of one or more Actions that complete a task.  This provides the opportunity to clearly name procedures being performed and extract away the detail.  Examples:

```
log_in_user(username)
log_user_out
add_secondary_account
add_mailing_address
remove_product_from_shopping_basket
```

Each of the above would then be defined as having several actual actions to complete the task, e.g. `login_user(username)` might be the following set of actions:

`click_login_button`
`type_user_name`
`type_user_password`
`click_submit_login`

So yes, the underlying functionality of WebDriver is still acting on the page using the same `.click` instructions.